# Why doesn't a button's onClickListener fire when a PopupWindow is showing over it's window?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, popupwindow

When a PopupWindow is showing, clicking a button outside of PopupWindow's area only dismisses the PopupWindow, but the button's click listener doesn't respond. My question is, why doesn't the button's click listener respond?

```
private OnClickListener mSiftClickListener = new 
    View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSiftPopwin != null && mSiftPopwin.isShowing()) {
                    ToastShow.makeText(mContext, "yes");  //never show
                } else {
                    showSfitPopwin();
                }
            }
    };
```

My `onClickListener` has two functions, `showSiftPopwin` and `ToastShow`, when Popwin is showing, click it again, Popwin dismiss but this onClick listener has't been invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

A popup window will consume any touch events on the screen until it is dismissed.  The touch event you mentioned does not get through to your button, and no click is performed.

You should move the button code into an [OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.OnDismissListener.html), if you want it to run whenever the window is dismissed.

Comment: Thank your your answer is great but if there are multiple buttons how to know which button is clicked..

Comment: @NavinRajPandey You can compare the IDs of the View passed as an argument to the IDs you want to listen for.